# Nodejs: execute then from Promise.all immediataly

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

As you can see i have created a list of async method.Inside async method in for loop i push some message by mqtt client into broker :

```
const example2 = async () => {
    await push();
    await push();
};
const push = async () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        client.publish(topic, message, pushOptions);
    }
}
var syncList = [];
const startpushing = () => {
    if (client.connected & client2.connected & client3.connected & client4.connected & client5.connected) {
        console.log(`start pushing`);
        syncList.push(
            example2(), example3(), example4(),...);
        Promise.all(syncList)
            .then(() => {
                console.log(topic_finished);
                client5.publish(topic_finished, "true", pushOptions);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}
```

I want after execute all async method i push new topic to broker so i used `Promise.all`.

But i do not know why `console.log(topic_finished)` executed soon when list of my task not finished yet?

I think it is because **i don't return anything** from my **async** method? Right? But what should I return?

Comment: Your `push` function is effectively synchronous, so it resolves immediately

Comment: > But what should I return?  You should return a Promise (resolve/reject).

Comment: Ok, but where?In client.publish or example2 ? @madflow

Comment: Promise.all expects an iterable of promises. Good starting point there.

Comment: I change my method to this: `const example2 = async () => {
    await push();
    await push();
    Promise.resolve();
};` and i tested again but result not change.@madflow

Answer (score -1):

You should push fns without invoking

```
syncList.push(example2, example2, ...anotherAsyncFns)
```

and add param in then

```
Promise.all(syncList).then((results) => console.log(results));
```